# Como se traduce el error #N/A de Excel en C#?

Tags: c#, excel, net

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion donde cada cinco segundos esta consultando un archivo en Excel mediante C#, en donde el excel tiene un hipervinculo con un copiado especial el cual trae datos de un PLC, dicho hipervinculo es de RSLinx, pero cuando el dato de RSLinx deja de recibir datos el Excel pone  #N/A y el programa en C# lo quiere tomar, pero no se como lo tome C#, ya intente comparandolo con null, 0 el metodo de IsNullorEmpty, desconozco como se traduce ese "error"

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("**********Modulos area de armado segundo paso**********");
        Console.WriteLine("Estado: En ejecucion");
        while (true)
        {
            recolectarDatos();
        }
    }

    static void recolectarDatos()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
                Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\N033321a\Desktop\modulos.xls");
                Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
                Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

                //Count of Raw and Columns in Excel
                int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

                //R,C ExtraigoLosValoresDeCadaCelda
                if ((xlRange.Cells[posicionesdatos[checaNulos[cont]], 3] as Excel.Range).Value != null) //En caso de que el modulo este parado, por lo regular cuando esta parado te manda un null, asi que con esta condicion lo evito
                {
                    cont++;
                    sqldate = DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MM-yyyy");
                    sqltime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
                    modulo = (xlRange.Cells[posicionesdatos[i], 2] as Excel.Range).Value;
                    operador = (xlRange.Cells[posicionesdatos[i], 3] as Excel.Range).Value;
}
```

Este es el error en Excel
[image: Error]

Comment: intentantaste comparando con "#N/A"?

Comment: Si y no funciono, intente con los valores que me daba de la excepcion como -2146233088

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes un error muy sencillo de solucionar, si la variable `modulo` está declarada como un `string` recibirás exactamente '#N/A' por lo que simplemente lo comparas con un `if` y decides que quieres hacer en caso de que eso ocurra.

También puede ocurrir que Excel muestre '#N/A' y C# reciba otro valor, por ejemplo un `string` vacío, sería el mismo caso. Simplemente pon un punto de interrupción en esa línea, observas el valor y montas el `if`.

Comment: Ya puse mi if evaluando ese error pero a la hora de debuguear como que no la toma 

if ((xlRange.Cells[posicionesdatos[i], 3] as Excel.Range).Equals("#N/A"))                                    i++;

Answer (score 0):

Estuve analizando y salian esos errores que estan en el if, lo corri y se resolvio mi problema para manejar el #N/A, aunque no se si sean varios tipos de errores con  #N/A

```
 if ((xlRange.Cells[posicionesdatos[i], 5] as Excel.Range).Value == -2146233088 || (xlRange.Cells[posicionesdatos[i], 5] as Excel.Range).Value == -2146826246) 
                    i++;
```